# Quoting table and column names in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a function that adds triggers to specified tables using this code ([full function code over here](https://github.com/hasgeek/coaster/blob/2f905d1a46932eca193a7628a44b189d814922bc/coaster/sqlalchemy/functions.py#L108-L196)):

```py
event.listen(primary_table, 'after_create', DDL('''
    CREATE FUNCTION {primary_table_name}_validate() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        target RECORD;
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.{rhs} IS NOT NULL) THEN
            SELECT {parentcol} INTO target FROM {child_table_name} WHERE {child_id_column} = NEW.{rhs};
            IF (target.{parentcol} != NEW.{lhs}) THEN
                RAISE foreign_key_violation USING MESSAGE = 'The target is not affiliated with this parent';
            END IF;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    CREATE TRIGGER {primary_table_name}_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON {primary_table_name}
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE {primary_table_name}_validate();
    '''.format(
    primary_table_name=primary_table_name,
    parentcol=parentcol,
    child_table_name=child_table_name,
    child_id_column=child_id_columns[0],
    lhs=parent_table_name + '_' + parent_id_columns[0],
    rhs=child_table_name + '_' + child_id_columns[0],
)).execute_if(dialect='postgresql'))

event.listen(primary_table, 'before_drop', DDL('''
    DROP TRIGGER {primary_table_name}_trigger ON {primary_table_name};
    DROP FUNCTION {primary_table_name}_validate();
    '''.format(primary_table_name=primary_table_name)).execute_if(dialect='postgresql'))
```

I don't want to be embedding raw strings in the SQL since it will choke on names like `user` (with PostgreSQL). I can't use SQLAlchemy's `bindparam` since these are table and column names, not data. [SQLAlchemy offers a `quoted_name`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.elements.quoted_name) [and a `quote_identifier`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/internals.html#sqlalchemy.sql.compiler.IdentifierPreparer.quote_identifier) that appear to do what I need, but how do I use them here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, using `DDL` with `context` dictionary does not seem to apply quoting to the substituted values the way we might hope.

Here is another pattern - create a custom [ExecutableDDLElement](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ExecutableDDLElement).

(Note `DDLElement` was renamed to `ExecutableDDLElement` in version 2.0, so change to `DDLElement` for 1.x code).

```py
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.schema import ExecutableDDLElement
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.compiler import DDLCompiler


class MyCreateTrigger(ExecutableDDLElement):

    # We contain state (table property), hence are not cacheable
    inherit_cache = False

    trigger_name: str
    func_name: str
    table: Table

    def __init__(self, table: Table):
        self.table = table
        name = table.name
        # Note: these could also be implemented as @property
        self.func_name = f"{name}_validate"
        self.trigger_name = f"{name}_trigger"
        # ... set any other properties (add them as arguments to __init__)


@compiles(MyCreateTrigger, "postgresql")
def visit_my_create_trigger(element: MyCreateTrigger, compiler: DDLCompiler, **kwargs) -> str:
    table = compiler.sql_compiler.process(element.table, asfrom=True, **kwargs)
    trigger_name = compiler.preparer.quote(element.trigger_name)
    func_name = compiler.preparer.quote(element.func_name)
    # (other properties you set on MyCreateTrigger can be accessed like element.foo).

    return (
        f"CREATE FUNCTION {func_name}() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ "
        "DECLARE "
            "target RECORD; "
        "BEGIN "
            "... " # (omitted)
        "END; "
        "$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; "
        f"CREATE TRIGGER {trigger_name} BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE "
        f"ON {table} "
        f"FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE {func_name}(); "
    )


event.listen(
    primary_table,
    "after_create",
    MyCreateTrigger(primary_table).execute_if(dialect="postgresql")
)
```

The main advantage of doing it this way is that you get access to the compiler, which lets you quote using `compiler.preparer.quote`.

There is also a `compiler.process`, which the docs suggest to use ([Compiling sub-elements of a custom expression construct](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/compiler.html#compiling-sub-elements-of-a-custom-expression-construct)), which quotes the name (and possible handles some other things).

I'm not sure how correct/idiomatic all this is, its just what I've figured out.

`compiler` is a `DDLCompiler`, which does not seem to be able to `process()` `Table`s, so we use its associated `SQLCompiler` (`sql_compiler` property). (see [Cross Compiling between SQL and DDL compilers](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/compiler.html#cross-compiling-between-sql-and-ddl-compilers)). It seems to need `asfrom=True`, even though it is not strictly a `FROM` clause. Without this parameter, I found it was emitting the empty string for the table name. I could not find documentation anywhere for `compiler.process` and supported parameters, but these parameters seem to be passed on to the internal component responsible for compiling each type of object, and I'm guessing `asfrom` means compile it as though it was appearing in a `FROM` clause.

I thought it is probably most correct to use `compiler.process` because the docs show this, however an alternative might be to just do `compiler.preparer.quote(table.name)`.

For the trigger and function name, I just used `compiler.preparer.quote`; I'm not sure how you can create a `Visitable` object that can be used with `compiler.process` for these.

`quote` seems to quote only if needed; `quote_identifier` always quotes. I have tested and `quote` seems to correctly handle reserved keywords in the dialect (e.g. "user" in postgresql, as mentioned in the question), and seems to be appropriate for this use case.

You can pass any extra parameters you need into your `MyCreateTrigger` constructor (and store them as properties), then use them in the `visit_my_create_trigger` function to generate the DDL string.

Column names should be able to be quoted/processed using `compiler.process` or `compiler.sql_compiler.process` on a `Column` instance. You probably want to pass in the actual `Column` (e.g. `table.c.foo`, instead of the string column name), so that it works with `compiler.process`. Otherwise you will need to dig into the compiler API and find the correct method for quoting column names (I'm not sure if `quote` is the correct method for this).

Note that the custom `DDLElement` has the same API as `DDL` (both inherit from `ExecutableDDLElement`), so you can use it with `event.listen` and use the `.execute_if` method with it.

`inherit_cache` and caching is explained in [Enabling Caching Support for Custom Constructs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/compiler.html#enabling-caching-support-for-custom-constructs). As I understand it, this kind of construct has state (`table` attribute), so should not be cacheable.

You can also easily support other dialects if needed by writing a similar function decorated by `@compiles(MyCreateTrigger, dialect)`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, `DDL` accepts a `context` dictionary that is applied to the SQL statement. This is the amended code:

```py
event.listen(primary_table, 'after_create',
    DDL('''
        CREATE FUNCTION %(function)s() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        DECLARE
            target RECORD;
        BEGIN
            IF (NEW.%(rhs)s IS NOT NULL) THEN
                SELECT %(parentcol)s INTO target FROM %(child_table_name)s WHERE %(child_id_column)s = NEW.%(rhs)s;
                IF (target.%(parentcol)s != NEW.%(lhs)s) THEN
                    RAISE foreign_key_violation USING MESSAGE = 'The target is not affiliated with this parent';
                END IF;
            END IF;
            RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
        CREATE TRIGGER %(trigger)s BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON %(table)s
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE %(function)s();
        ''',
        context={
            'table': primary_table_name,
            'function': '%s_validate' % primary_table_name,
            'trigger': '%s_trigger' % primary_table_name,
            'parentcol': parentcol,
            'child_table_name': child_table_name,
            'child_id_column': child_id_columns[0],
            'lhs': '%s_%s' % (parent_table_name, parent_id_columns[0]),
            'rhs': '%s_%s' % (child_table_name, child_id_columns[0]),
        }
    ).execute_if(dialect='postgresql')
)

event.listen(primary_table, 'before_drop',
    DDL('''
        DROP TRIGGER %(trigger)s ON %(table)s;
        DROP FUNCTION %(function)s();
        ''',
        context={
            'table': primary_table_name,
            'trigger': '%s_trigger' % primary_table_name,
            'function': '%s_validate' % primary_table_name,
        }
    ).execute_if(dialect='postgresql')
)
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like this and also discovered the DDL context parameter. However, it seems that it is not quoting the values from the context dictionary. Try using a table name with spaces in it.
I also tried using e.g. `context={'trigger': quoted_name('%s_trigger' % primary_table_name, True)}` but that also didn't work.
This is on sqlite by the way so maybe postgresql is different.
Mostly tables have names that don't need escaping, and the names are within developers control, so this problem probably wouldn't come up much. But it would be nice to know how to do this properly.

Comment: Its a bit unclear how to use quote_identifier, something like this maybe?
`from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql;
quote_identifier = postgresql.dialect().identifier_preparer.quote_identifier`
Then manually quote the names using quote_identifier in the context dictionary. Or skip the context dictionary altogether and just use python's string substitution for the ddl statement like you were originally.
It locks you into a single dialect (which you are already in your example).